# How to check logs for - Error: Could not connect, retrying (3/3) - Not able to ssh into Instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a **GCP instance** which was running successfully until last week. But suddenly I am not able to ssh into it. I am getting the error

> Could not connect, retrying (3/3)

When I tried to find the root cause of it. I somehow managed to learn about os-login and configured it in the instance metadata.

Though my os-login setup was successful and was able to ssh through os-login I am not able to access it since it asks for username and password which I don't have any clue on what to give. I tried so many articles but still failed to understand what to give in that.

I can easily delete the instance and set up it from scratch but all I worry is I am not able to find the root cause of it.

Can someone help me what are the ways to find out the **logs/cause** for why I am not able to ssh into it suddenly?

I tried seeing the instance logs from the options in the console. But it did not have much info.

Comment: Most likely the public IP address for your instance has changed. Login to the Google Cloud Console and check the IP address. Unless you know what you are doing, revert the changes you made to use OS Login. I also recommend rebooting the system. Then test by clicking the SSH button next to your Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I rebooted my system. Tried Os login too. Still not able to ssh. It would be easier if i could find any logs relating to that somewhere :(

Comment: Please reread my comment. Reverse OS Login. Then use the SSH button in the Google Cloud Console. Otherwise, provide the exact commands that you are using to connect to your remote instance. Stackdriver does not log SSH connections unless you set that up manually. You can use the Serial Port to view the startup including SSH server activity. Have you tried accessing the serial port in the Google Cloud Console? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output

Comment: Note: Google Cloud does not use SSH username/password unless you modified the SSH server configuration. Google services use Public/Private key pairs.

Comment: Sure I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Please do as the @John Hanley suggested and post your results.

Comment: did you find out what the issue was? How did you solve?